# What does 'Going to want to' mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across a song titled *All You Are Going To Want To Do Is Get Back There.*

Can someone explain the grammar behind '*going to want to*' and what the entire sentence means? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unusual construction that used in certain contexts.

For example, if a child tells a parent:

> I don't want to go to the shops.

The parent might respond:

> After I tell you a secret, you are going to want to go to the shops.

That's to say, you are going to change your mind, to see why visiting the shops is an attractive option.

In the song title, the writer is saying that whatever happens **there** is so attractive that all your desires will be focused on returning there. It is the only thing that you are going to want to do.

That's to say: **going to want to do** is the same as **will want to do**.